# What is the meaning of elliptical in this context?

Tags: meaning, terminology, philosophy

> ...and it is this possibility, which is clearly provided for in language, that has encouraged a rival idea (8), namely that needing is always by its nature needing for a purpose - any purpose at all that may be specified -
> and that statements of need which do not mention relevant purposes are somehow **elliptical** (according to some, dishonestly **elliptical**) for sentences that do not mention them(9). One thing seems right with the **elliptical** view and another seems wrong. Let's take the right thing first.

Any search of elliptical means 'having been omitted', I fail to see how this applies here.

Comment: Please give at least one dictionary definition. The first definitions I came across for the linguistic sense were 'using or involving ellipsis' ... 'language that is extremely/excessively terse, omissions possibly making it hard to understand' (I'm paraphrasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> statements of need which do not mention relevant purposes are somehow **elliptical** (according to some, dishonestly elliptical) for sentences that do not mention them

In this case the sentences have an element that is omitted, e.g.

*"I need a hammer"*

In itself, this is a good sentence but is it a shortened form of

*"I need a hammer [in order] to hammer this nail into this wood."*?

Thus stating the purpose of the need.

Comment: Ah, this helps a lot, especially since the essay itself concerned need. Thanks a lot